# convert .mov to .m4v with mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

What do I need to type into the mac terminal to be able to convert my `.mov` files to `.m4a`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

With ffmpeg installed:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.m4v`

This will perform an exact copy of both the audio and video streams into the new file.

Comment: how do i install ffmpeg? i downloaded the files, but theres no install. its just libraries for developers

Comment: The simplest way is to install Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) then from the command line, do `brew install ffmpeg`

Comment: or you can install from port:
$ port install ffmpeg

Comment: this command always lead for an error. below is works for me.
`ffmpeg -I input.MOV output.mp4`

Comment: That's odd because even `man ffmpeg` shows the lowercase `-i` used for input files.

Comment: Yeah. The copy flags gave me errors. Just '-i' was all I needed.

Answer (score 22):

I guess I am little late in the game, but researching on the very same topic today, I found nowadays MacOS ships with `avconvert`:

```
AVCONVERT(1)              BSD General Commands Manual             AVCONVERT(1)

NAME
     avconvert -- movie conversion tool

SYNOPSIS
     avconvert [-hvq] --p <preset_name> --s <source_media> --o <output_movie>

DESCRIPTION
 avconvert can be used to compress video media to different types for sharing on the
 web or loading onto devices.

 -h       prints usage information and available presets

 -v       sets the console output to verbose

 -q       sets the console output to quiet

 -prog    shows progress during the export (default with -v)

 -p | --preset name
          converts the source media to an output file using the specified preset. Use
          --listPresets to get the full list. Common presets are:

          PresetAppleM4VCellular
          PresetAppleM4ViPod
          PresetAppleM4VWiFi
          PresetAppleM4VAppleTV
          PresetAppleM4V480pSD
          PresetAppleM4V720pHD
          PresetAppleM4V1080pHD
          PresetAppleM4A
```

Comment: this is the right answer using standard macOS tools.

Comment: This answer needs some serious SEO. This is literally the ONLY place on the internet I can find `avconvert` when I search for "mac native tool convert video formats".

Comment: Fantastic find. Thank you.

Comment: Example: Something like this should do: `avconvert -s input.mov -o output.m4a -p PresetAppleM4A` you can find the presets via: `avconvert --help -p`. In my case I wanted an mp4 so I went with: `avconvert -s input.mov -o output.mp4 -p PresetHEVCHighestQuality`

Answer (score 1):

**1.** get brew

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

**2.** get ffmpeg

`brew install ffmpeg`

**3a.** convert audio only with ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -acodec copy output.m4a`

**3b.** convert both video & audio with ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.m4v`